Java criteria builder
Can you help me to create a criteriabuilder implementation from this SQL?
SELECT a.*
   FROM 
     MY_TABLE a
 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
    
        ELL_ID, 
        STATUS, 
        MAX(COALESCE(MOD_DATE, CREA_DATE)) AS MAX_DATE
    FROM 
        MY_TABLE b
    GROUP BY  ELL_ID, STATUS
) b

ON 
    a.ELL_ID = b.ELL_ID
    AND a.STATUS = b.STATUS
    AND COALESCE(a.MOD_DATE, a.CREA_DATE) = b.MAX_DATE
WHERE a.MOD_DATE >= TO_DATE('2024.12.01', 'YYYY.MM:DD');


I try lots of implement but I dont have a good idea.
Unfortunately, I was unable to implement the group by expression in the subquery.
And here is my implementation:
 CriteriaQuery<MyTableEntity> statusMainQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(MyTableEntity.class);
        Root<MyTableEntity> status = statusMainQuery.from(MyTableEntity.class);

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (searchDto.getStatusChange() != null) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(status.get("status"), searchDto.getStatusChange()));
        }
        if (searchDto.getStatusChangeDate() != null) {
            List<Predicate> creaDatePredicates = new ArrayList<>();
            creaDatePredicates.add(criteriaBuilder.isNull(status.get("modDate")));
            creaDatePredicates.addAll(
                    CriteriaPredicateHelper.getCriteriaFilterDateValue(
                            status, "creaDate", searchDto.getStatusChangeDate(),
                            criteriaBuilder, true, LocalDateType.LOCALDATETIME));
            predicates.add(
                    criteriaBuilder.or(
                            criteriaBuilder.and(creaDatePredicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])),
                            criteriaBuilder.and(
                                    CriteriaPredicateHelper.getCriteriaFilterDateValue(
                                            status, "modDate", searchDto.getStatusChangeDate(),
                                            criteriaBuilder, true, LocalDateType.LOCALDATETIME).toArray(new Predicate[0])
                            )
                    )
            );
        }

        Subquery<Object[]> subquery = statusMainQuery.subquery(Object[].class);
        Root<MyTableEntity> subRoot = subquery.from(MyTableEntity.class);
        Expression<LocalDate> maxDateExpression = criteriaBuilder.greatest(criteriaBuilder.coalesce(subRoot.get("modDate"), subRoot.get("creaDate")));
/* This is not working
        Expression<Object[]> selection = criteriaBuilder.array(
                subRoot.get("ellId"),
                subRoot.get("status"),
                maxDateExpression
        );
        subquery.select(selection)
                .groupBy(subRoot.get("ellId"), subRoot.get("status"));
*/
        List<MyTableEntity> entities = entityManager.createQuery(statusMainQuery).getResultList();

